# How Can I Embed a Dashboard in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I'm embedding a dashboard in a visualforce page using an iframe:

```
<iframe src="/01ZJ00000007JGa?isdtp=vw"/>
```

When I try to click on any component to load the underlying report, I get this javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Listener' of undefined   iframeinterface.js:1
Sfdc.xdomain.IframeInterface.handleOnload                          iframeinterface.js:1
window.onload                                                      crossDomainProxy.html:6
```

The affected file is served from `<SFHOST>/xdomain/iframeinterface.js` and the specific line that's causing the error is:

```
("sfdc-console" === b ? top : 
    "undefined" !== typeof a.targetParentFrame ? 
         parent.frames[a.targetParentFrame].frames[b] : 
             parent.frames[b]
).Sfdc.xdomain.Listener.accept(a)
```

Any thoughts about what's going wrong and how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

I was able to accomplish what I need to with the following hack described in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8809/63), made possible by the fact that I'm on the same domain.  But I'll leave the question open, looking for a more thorough explanation and non-hackish way to embed a dashboard in Visualforce.

Comment: Is the purpose of isdtp just to strip off the headers and footers of the dash and just expose the dashboard? I tried with lt and mn params it seems to work, with vw (http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html)I get the same domain error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'xdomain' of undefined

Comment: Interesting... And yes, I'm using isdtp to hide headers since this is embedded.  Confirmed that links work with `mn` (although it's ugly)

Comment: Update:  seems like the problem happens in the srcUp method. It only happens when clicking on chart images, not on table components

Comment: Why bother building a Visual Force page when you can just use this code directly in an HTML Area Home Page component? < iframe src="/000000000000000?isdtp=vw" frameborder="0" height="768" width="1024"></iframe> The 000000000000000 is your Dashboard page ID. It displays the Dashboard seamlessly. But, I face the same problem you're all talking about, which is that the links don't work. Is there an HTML solution rather than Apex?

Comment: @Jim, because I don't *want* it on my homepage - I want it embedded in another page. But yes, the solution accepted as an answer below uses Javascript (not Apex) to solve the broken links issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading the Dashboard with `isdtp` removes the header and sidebar, but isn't officially supported.  When you do this, SFDC replaces all the links with a call to the `srcUp()` function, which doesn't work in this context.

To get around that, add the following script to your VF page to change the links back:

```
<apex:page>

<script>
jQuery( function ($) {

     $('#iframeID').load( function() {              
         var $frameDoc = this.contentWindow.document,
             urlMatch = /srcUp\(%27(.*)%27\)/;

         $('a[href*="srcUp"]', $frameDoc).each( function () {
             this.href = decodeURIComponent(this.href.match(urlMatch)[1]);
         });
     });

});
</script>

<!-- the rest of your page goes here -->

<iframe id="iframeID" src="/01ZJ00000007JGa?isdtp=vw"/>
```

Comment: I tried the code mentioned above but I got this error in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined". am I missing something? `<apex:page> <script>
jQuery( function ($) { $('#iframeID').load( function() { var $frameDoc = this.contentWindow.document, urlMatch = /srcUp\(%27(.*)%27\)/; $('a[href*="srcUp"]', $frameDoc).each( function () { this.href = decodeURIComponent(this.href.match(urlMatch)[1]); }); }); });
</script> <!-- the rest of your page goes here --> <iframe id="iframeID" src="/01ZJ00000007JGa?isdtp=vw"/>`

Comment: Yup.  You'll need to have jQuery loaded on your page. Easiest way is to add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` to the top of your visualforce page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, salesforce blocks the script from reaching the other domain.

Answer (score 0):

When I have run across this problem, I ended up re-creating the charts I needed using the analytics:chart tag on a Visualforce page.  Not the same as embedding, but it is fully supported. It does mean more maintenance as any changes to the dashboard have to be manually updated. In my particular use case it worked well for them but YMMV.

Answer (score -3):

With Spring 15 release, iFrame is not supported by Salesforce anymore. So we need to have an alternative way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: (1) what do you mean that iframe is no longer supported by Salesforce?  This question is about embedding dashboards in Visualforce, and AFAIK there are no limitations on including iframes in a VF page.... (2) This isn't really an answer, so please changing it to a comment on the question or another answer.

Comment: Please refer for link below:     https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XttAAE