# adding a graph to a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-platform

Is it possible to add a graph or dashboard element or dashboard to visualforce page? Can this page be made to display in Salesforce1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You will need to embed the dashboard in your VF page using Iframes.

```
<apex:iframe src="link to your dashboard" scrolling="true"/>
```

This is a similar question which should help you. 
[How Can I Embed a Dashboard in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/how-can-i-embed-a-dashboard-in-visualforce)

Also, look at this. 
http://vanityforce.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/two-methods-for-embedding-a-report-or-dashboard-chart-in-visualforce-or-standard-pagelayout/

You can also use VF charting or google APIs and build a lot more graph/chart components to your VF page.