# Custom salesforce dashboard on a Visual force page, Is there any way to do this?

Tags: visualforce, dashboard

I have tried using apex:iframe, but it displays a blank page

using     apex:iframe

```
 <apex:page showheader="true" sidebar="true">
    <apex:iframe src="/01Z2w000000ooGVEAY/" height="600px" width="70%"/>
</apex:page>
```

Then I had tried using wave:dashboard

```
<apex:page showheader="true" sidebar="true">
 <wave:dashboard dashboardId="01Z2w000000ooGVEAY" 
        showTitle="true" 
        height="800px" 
        openLinksInNewWindow="true" />            
</apex:page>  

                                                                                                   The result was a blank page, for both cases
```

Comment: please provide a code

Comment: This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/150712/30493) looks to be pointing you in the right direction.